# MySql equal row incorrect when contain HTML tag

Tags: mysql

When the row value is contain HTML Tag, like

```
|---------------|-------------------------------------|
|  ID           |  CONTENT                            |
|---------------|-------------------------------------|
|  1            | <a href="#">abcdefg</a>             |
|---------------|-------------------------------------|
```

Then

`SELECT count(1) FROM record WHERE content = '<a href="#">abcdefg</a>'`

Will return `0` forever

And I also tried `STRCMP`, `LIKE`

`SELECT count(1) FROM record WHERE STRCMP(content, '<a href="#">abcdefg</a>') = 0` 
`SELECT count(1) FROM record WHERE content LIKE '%<a href="#">abcdefg</a>%'`

Both return `0`

How to equal row in MySql when contain a HTML Tag?

Comment: show your table structure, as html tag should not be any issue.

Comment: maybe your field containst encoded data, what if you search for `content = '&lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;abcdefg&lt;/a&gt;'` ?

Comment: @ZafarMalik I just found the content structure is `content varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL`. Does the `utf8mb4` caused this issue?

Comment: it is not related with CHARACTER SET utf8mb4  as I am able to search at my end, may be with specific version, share your version.

Comment: plz use following statement just to clear some doubt- "SELECT * FROM `record` WHERE `content`='\<\a \href\=\"\#\"\>\abcdefg\<\/\a\>';" and check if you are getting any row.

Comment: @ZafarMalik The version is `5.6.24 MySQL Community Server (GPL)`, but I created another table with same structure except not set `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 ` on the new table, then the equal return 1. And I just search for utf8mb4, this encoding is using for store emoji

Comment: @Joe: check if fthiella's comment is valid

Comment: @Joe:- Your query seems to be working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f322/2

Comment: @ZafarMalik @RahulTripathi @fthiella @Ravinder Reddy . I find out why, sorry for late cause busy working. Before insert into MySql, the data was handled by Java and the data changed. What I have seen is not the really data, the data after Java process contains more invisible characters. I can get `1` result if I copy the condition `<a href="#">abcdefg</a>` from Java output